# issue occuring on threading in different instances by using c#.net

Tags: c#, multithreading

here i am using c#.net window service, the record which was lying in database with one particular column as null those records it will fetch and it will create a text file and it update a status as FG, while when if i start the service at that instance if any records having status as null it was generating properly and updated, in another instance if suppose new records comes in to database this thread was not getting started if we wantedly do restart the service means it was taking existing record, how to solve this issue can any one guide me please

```
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)) // Transaction Scope Started
    {
        try
        {
            if (threadCTD == null)
            {
                threadCTD = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForCTD));  // Thread Initialize for CTD 

                DataSet samdsCTD = new DataSet();
                DataAccessLayer objDbAccessCTD = new DataAccessLayer();
                samdsCTD = objDbAccessCTD.getFilesFromDataBase(strSelectProcedureName, "ECD");
                if (samdsCTD.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && samdsCTD.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    samdsCTD.Dispose();

                    if ((threadCTD == null) || (threadCTD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) || (threadCTD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted) || (threadCTD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Aborted))
                        threadCTD.Start();  // Thread Started for ITD 
                }
                samdsCTD.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}
        finally
        {
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would really help if you could clean up your code before posting - indent it more sanely so we can see the relevant bits, get rid of the commented out lines etc. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @jon skeet as per requested i have done the same

Comment: Not really - look at all the blank lines and the intentation which is *way* more than it needs to be.

Comment: Sorry, I have read and re-read the question, can't get a handle on it.  You you rephrase it please.

Answer (score 0):

There should a loop that frequently check the database for new records.

Your code does not seem to have this loop that will iterate and check the database for the new records. Is there any other piece of code that call the code you shown above that does this?
If yes, could you post that too?